# How to process a datatable that has been split into multiple equal datatables

Tags: c#, linq

I have a main datatable with a variable number of rows (upwards of hundreds at a time) that I need to split into separate datatables for performance reasons.  I was able to use the below code to successfully break the original table up into multiple tables in an array, with 20 rows in each.

```
DataTable[] splittables = tbl.AsEnumerable()
   .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
   .GroupBy(x => x.index / 20)  // integer division, the fractional part is truncated
   .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.row).CopyToDataTable())
   .ToArray();
```

However, being fairly new to C#, I wasn't able to figure out how to use the broken-up tables from that split array.  I need to be able to loop through each of the split table chunks and do the same block of work on each subtable, i.e., do work on split table 1 (first 20 rows), then do the same work on split table 2 (next 20 rows), then do the same work on split table 3 (next 20 rows), etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you planning on using tasks/threads to process each block of 20 rows this can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now have an array of `DataTable` so at its simplest you can simply iterate over the array executing some method

```
foreach(var dataTable in splittables) 
{
    DoWork(dataTable)
}

private void DoWork(DataTable table)
{
   // do your work
}
```

Comment: That's perfect!  And far more straightforward than I was trying to come at it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: if you DO NOT run `DoWork` inside a tasks/thread it would be just data manipulation without much benefit - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming